# python pyhanko pdf cms signature validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, digital-signature, pyhanko

i need a pdf cms vlidation pyhanko was the best amoung them (open to suggestion)
in cli i use this command

```
python -m pyhanko sign validate --pretty-print --no-diff-analysis --no-strict-syntax download.pdf
```

and i face two problem

```
ERROR - An error occurred while validating this signature: The algorithm sha256_rsa is not allowed by the current usage policy. Reason: Key size 1024 for algorithm rsassa_pkcs1v15 is considered too small; policy mandates >= 2048. [AdESIndeterminate.CRYPTO_CONSTRAINTS_FAILURE]
```

and

```
An error occurred while validating this signature: The algorithm sha1 is not allowed by the current usage policy. [AdESIndeterminate.CRYPTO_CONSTRAINTS_FAILURE] Error: Validation failed
```

in code not any better

```
pdf_file = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
validatino = ValidationContext()
for sig in pdf_file.embedded_signatures:
    print("*" * 10, sig, "*" * 10)
   try:
       status = validate_pdf_signature(sig)
      print(status.pretty_print_details())
   except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

one exception is

```
/Type
```

and other one is:

```
The algorithm sha1 is not allowed by the current usage policy, [AdESIndeterminate.CRYPTO_CONSTRAINTS_FAILURE]
```

i used 'pdfsig' in terminal and it works right
it returns all datas fine
i kinda know i should use my own policy in pyhanko but confused in doing that and i belive that there is a set of instrucation here that can help me in validation of these datas in my code

i tried pyhanko(python package) - pdfsig (trminal tool)- endesive (python package and some sample)